# Using C# assemblies from VB6 code. Some issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vb6, interop, .net-2.0

I have a C# assembly, which is `regasm`ed, but is not in the GAC.  In my VB6 code, I added a reference to the generated type library (the .tlb file).

Then I instantiate the C# lib in my VB6 code.  If I run it from the VB6 IDE, it does not work.     The `Set` in the code below:

```
Dim obj as MyCSharpNamespace.MyCSharpObject
Set obj = New MyCSharpNamespace.MyCSharpObject
```

causes this error:

```
Automation error 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

However, if I compile the VB6 project to an EXE and run it, it runs perfectly fine.

I should add that all the VB6 project files (e.g. forms, modules, etc...) are in the same folder as the C# DLL and TLB.

So why can't I run it from the IDE environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `/codebase` switch when running `regasm`.